# Forward Stream using ASP.Net WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm using .Net Core 2.0 to develop my ASP.Net API and I want to make request for external public stream and forward it with my own GET route.

The external stream is an MJPEG content-type.

Since I'm using the latest version of .NET Core, the PushStreamContent is not available anymore.

This is the class that takes care of the Connection and Stream process:

```
 internal class LiveViewStream
{
    HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    public Stream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    public Stream GetVideoTCP()
    {
        string url = "http://87.139.76.248:8081/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg";

        return webClient.OpenRead(url);
    }

    public void Main()
    {
        var bytesRead = 0;
        var buffer = new byte[65536];

        using (Stream stream = GetVideoTCP())
        {
            do
            {
                bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            while (stream.Position != stream.Length);

        }
    }
```

And this is the GET route:

```
// GET: api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var video = new LiveViewStream();

        video.Main();

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        response.Content = new StreamContent(video.outputStream);

        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/x-motion-jpeg");

        return response;
}
```

This code gives me error with `while` method not being supported. I have tried different methods, and they didn't work, I would either get a file when making a GET request or nothing.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using Socket TCP server and forwarding the images with a custom MjpegWriter to client-socket.